# Integrated Authentication Error with Infogix Data360 Analyze

Tags: jdbc, integrated-security

Encountered an issue using integrated authentication in a JDBC Query node in Data360 Analyze v3.6.5. Below is how we solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download "sqljdbc42.jar" from Microsoft (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774)
2. Place the downloaded file anywhere on the computer or server.
3. In the node properties enter the path to the file in the "DbDriverClasspath" property.

[image]

Thanks,
Josh